# Load multiple java .fxml

Tags: java, javafx, memory, memory-leaks, fxml

i'm developing a java application using javafx as framework to design the UI.

But i encountered a problem: when i load some .fxml files, i noticed that probably previous files that were loaded, remains in memory, so the application, after some file loading, takes up a lot of memory, so the program needs to be closed in short.

Maybe, the problem is how i load that java fxml files, so now i would post here the code. But i can't undestand how to manage memory at this time. Maybe you can help me..

This is the code:

```
AnchorPane pane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Home.fxml"));
        
rootPane.getChildren().setAll(pane);
```

For example here i'm loading the resource called "Home.fxml"

Probably i need to delete from memory every fxml that i load. Thank you!

Comment: The UI you load from an FXML file behaves like any other Java object; as long as you have no references to it, it will be garbage collected automatically, freeing up the memory. There's no direct way in Java to delete things from memory.

Comment: Ok, thank you. So now i feel confused. I can’t undestand why loading multiple fxml the application memory loaded is very high... Is there another method to load fxml files?

Comment: @LuigiDaddario Did you try `rootPane.getChildren().clear();' before `rootPane.getChildren().setAll(pane);` ?

Comment: @Otabek Karimov yes, i tried but it still not work..

Comment: [mcve] please..